# android chromium resourceExtractor error

Tags: android, resources, chromium, extractor

Suddenly my app in production phase started to get Chromium ResourceExtractor errors in api 7 even though I had not changed anything in the app.
Is there any solution or update for this error?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException
       at org.chromium.base.ResourceExtractor$ExtractTask.doInBackground$51DKOQJ1EPGIUR31DPJIULJFD5I3MAACD9GNCO9FDHGMSPPFAPNMIP1R0(ResourceExtractor.java:24)
       at org.chromium.base.ResourceExtractor$ExtractTask.doInBackground(ResourceExtractor.java:78)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)



Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException
       at org.chromium.base.ResourceExtractor$ExtractTask.doInBackground$51DKOQJ1EPGIUR31DPJIULJFD5I3MAACD9GNCO9FDHGMSPPFAPNMIP1R0(ResourceExtractor.java:52)
       at org.chromium.base.ResourceExtractor$ExtractTask.doInBackground(ResourceExtractor.java:78)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
Caused by java.io.IOException
       at org.chromium.base.ResourceExtractor$ExtractTask.extractResourceHelper(ResourceExtractor.java:15)
       at org.chromium.base.ResourceExtractor$ExtractTask.doInBackground$51DKOQJ1EPGIUR31DPJIULJFD5I3MAACD9GNCO9FDHGMSPPFAPNMIP1R0(ResourceExtractor.java:47)
       at org.chromium.base.ResourceExtractor$ExtractTask.doInBackground(ResourceExtractor.java:78)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

Comment: There is an ongoing investigation about this issue on Android Issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64926437

Comment: Thank you, that's also reported by me. This is another issue which is being processing by Chromium https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=542151

Comment: This issue has been solved by Chromium developers which has been recently deployed to devices. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=758984#c5